# How do I simulate an expired coupon when testing stripe payments locally in React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am setting up different bug severity levels in a stripe hook, and want to be able to see the specific error messages that a user sees. Testing that a card has declined is straightforward, [this documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) has a bunch of useful card numbers to simulate different failures.

What I want to do, and where I am getting stuck, is find a similar easy way of locally testing an expired coupon. I want to be able to run my code locally, input either a card or special coupon number, and simulate what the user sees when they try to use an expired coupon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a coupon that could be used only once and then try to use it twice.

Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create

[image]